# Why Would Unknown Column Be Referenced in SQL Query

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am in the process of updating some SQL queries to run against MariaDB instead of via SQL Anywhere. One query I'm running is erroring with this:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'choice' in 'field list'
```

That is for this query:

```
   SELECT 
    (select firstname||' '||lastname||'  ('||service||')' from staff_members where id_number = customer_assignment_reviews.staff_member_id) as Rep,
    (select customer_firstname||' '|| customer_lastname from customers where id_number = customer_assignment_reviews.cs_id) as Cus,
    last_modified as "Response Date",replace(review_reason,'’','') as "Reason",
    (Select choice = CASE
     when accepted = 0 then 'No'
     when accepted = 1 then 'Yes'
     end) as "Accepted?"
    FROM customer_assignment_reviews
    where staff_member_id in (Select id_number from kar.staff_members where division_id = 6)
    and "Response Date" between today() - 7  and today() /* Date Range */
    and "Accepted?" = 'No'
    Order by 3 desc
```

Is this error message as straightforward as it sounds? It's simply saying the column "choice" doesn't exist on the target table?

I'm just trying to reason through why this code (which I inherited) would be referencing a column that does not exist. Could something be expected here at runtime?

Comment: Note that you need `PIPES_AS_CONCAT` in `SQL_MODE`, else `||` will be treated as `OR` and you will get strange results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use subquery in `SELECT` list

```
SELECT
-- ...
(Select choice = CASE
     when accepted = 0 then 'No'
     when accepted = 1 then 'Yes'
     end) as "Accepted?"

=>
SELECT
     CASE
       when accepted = 0 then 'No'
       when accepted = 1 then 'Yes'
     end as "Accepted?"
```

---

Additionaly syntax `SELECT alias = expression` is only T-SQL specific:

```
SELECT alias = 1 
<=>
SELECT 1 AS alias
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this supposed to mean?

```
(Select choice = CASE
 when accepted = 0 then 'No'
 when accepted = 1 then 'Yes'
 end) as "Accepted?"
```

Very importantly, a `select` is not needed here.  You might mean:

```
(case when accepted = 0 then 'No'
      when accepted = 1 then 'Yes'
 end) as is_accepted  -- prefer to not have to need escape characters
```

If `accepted` only takes those two values, you can simplify this to:

```
elt(accepted + 1, 'No', 'Yes') as is_accepted
```